Explicit field extension for semistable models of curves
The paper arxiv:1211.4624 briefly summarizes the way to find a  semistable model of a curve $X/K$ (the existence of the model is ensured by the Deligne-Mumford theorem). Specifically the author says the following:

In a way the proof of  Deligne and Mumford is constructive: choose $n ≥ 3$ prime to the residue characteristic of $K$ and let $L/K$ be the smallest field extension over which the $n$-torsion points of the jacobian of $X$ become rational. Then the minimal regular model of $X_L$ is semistable. In theory, this gives an algorithm to determine a semistable model. It seems, however, that several steps in this algorithm are today still computationally too expensive to be practical for curves of genus $g ≥ 3$.

What is the actual difficulty in finding the mentioned finite field extension $L/K$? Is it just a computational problem or is it a conceptual obstruction? Is there a general algortihm that explicitely finds the semistable model?
For instance in Liu's book Proposition 10.4.6 gives a recipe under some hypotheses on the multiplicities of the irreducible compoments of the singular fibres.

The Galois action on torsion points lands in GSp(2g, Z/n) whose size grows rather rapidly with g and n. So the kernel of this rep will typically have quite enormous degree.
